# Save Image from user Drawn PictureBox whose SizeMode=stretch in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawing, gdi+

Im drawing an image on picture box which is in stretch mode,I translate the mouse coordinates on  the mouse click event by using a function to obtain the real coordinates and draw the image by overriding the on-paint event and using the paint event Graphics.
Since the picture box is set to stretch i only obtain a small size image when i try to save the image by using `picturebox.DrawtoBitmap` Function.The extra parts are padded with Black colour.Please help me out.

Comment: If you know how to draw it into a picture box then you know how to draw it into *any* bitmap.  Graphics.ScaleTransform is your friend.

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width,
                               pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height)) {
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
    g.DrawImage(yourBitmap,
                new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                new Rectangle(0, 0, yourImage.Width, yourImage.Height),
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
  }
  bmp.Save(@"c:\yourfile.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```